# PHP getcwd() function to be used with include or require in different directories

Tags: php, include-path, getcwd

I need to include a path from a config file in one directory on other scrpits a few directories up or down.

My config file has a function like this:

```
$execute_path = getcwd() . "/execute.php";
```

The execute.php file resides in the same directory as the config file wich makes it ok and the output will become:

```
public-html/config-directory/execute.php
```

Now if use the same function in a directory that is outside of the original directory, it treats the getcwd() function as if it was in that directory.

For example, if call it from a directory public-html/one/two/three/somefile.php as follow:

```
<?php 
include(pathto/config.php)
echo $execute_path;
?>
```

The output becomes publichtml/one/two/three/execute.php rather than staying publichtml/config-directory/execute.php

How can I achieve what I want here? Sorry for the long explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include can be very tricky why i advice is

```
//config.php

define("SITE_PATH", "public-html/config-directory");


//execute.php

$execute_path =SITE_PATH . "/execute.php";

//run.php
include_once 'config.php';
include_once 'execute.php';

echo $execute_path;
```

Comment: The problem is that config file is generated based on the users server setting, and wherever they uploaded the main (it's a plugin) directory. Which means defining the path manually in the config fie is not going to work.

Comment: Its safer since because its config and you would not be using it in working directory all the time `getcwd()` would only return current working directory

Comment: I could use the getcwd when the config file is being written and use it as you describe. Instead of having a function it would become a path so the cofig would read: $execute_path = "path/execute.php"

Comment: its not a function ... it a constant .. there are so many ways to get working directory `__DIR__` , `basename(__FILE__)` etc .. but for a config file ... no no no .. you need a base

Comment: So i'm using a form to get the user input, and the post to the config file. How can i get the complete path and add the file name and post it to the config?

Comment: `basename(__DIR__) . "/config.php`  that would get parent dir or `basename(__FILE__) . "/config.php`  current dir

Comment: basename(__DIR__) . "/config.php"; works great but it only get the path up to the base, and not all the way from the start (public-html blah blah). Is there any way that i can get the complete path? thanks a million for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: run the base name twice .. you know i don't know your current settings ..but i would advice but the know the installation path use that to `basename` or `dirname` to the config path then save the settings

Comment: I ended up doing this way `$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/execute.php";` By including this in the config file at the time of creation. Thanks again for your help.